# Are there standard measures of adhesion?

Tags: adhesion

I am looking for quantitative indicators of how well water displays adhesion with respect to other materials like glass, metal, wood...did not find anything immediately on a google search. I need only rough indicators- the values are not being used for any important application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

- If you're looking for equipment to measure adhesion, there are commercial products, such as [these from DeFelsko](https://www.defelsko.com/resources/measurement-of-adhesion-strength) (which also has an inrtroduction to testing).
- If your looking for standards for testing, there are many, such as [ASTM D4541](https://www.astm.org/d4541-22.html) Standard Test Method for Pull-Off Strength of Coatings Using Portable Adhesion Testers.
- If you're looking for some lab exercises in measuring adhesion, there are online resources such as from [the University of Akron](https://www.uakron.edu/polymer/agpa-k12outreach/lesson-plans/adhesives-measuring-stickiness),  [the University of Hawaii](https://manoa.hawaii.edu/exploringourfluidearth/chemical/properties-water/hydrogen-bonds-make-water-sticky/activity-cohesion-and-adhesion) and [Rohm & Haas](https://www.juliantrubin.com/encyclopedia/chemistry/adhesive_experiments.html).
- If you're designing your own experiment, consider different ways adhesion is measured, e.g. by peeling, by pulling perpendicularly, etc. Also consider the units of measurement.

You could make some simple test equipment, using a spring scale to measure the force needed to separate two plaques (e.g., squares of metal, microscope slides or wood).

Comment: Thank you Dr. Moishe- these are helpful links. Would there be a table of standard values somewhere? Is there a standard unit of measurement that specifies how well a liquid-solid would adhere? I am especially looking for values fo substances that would NOT be used as glue... like water, honey, oil etc.

Comment: the DeFelsk link above lists a number of testing standards for coatings. As for adhesion of water (and ice), this is of major importance in many areas, such as aircraft. See https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/am1006035, for example. A simple test can be performed with water and microscope slides. Note that measurements will be quite *rate dependent* for liquids; a quick pull will snap the glass slides before the water "lets go".